# Trying to add text from text boxes to SQL table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use SQL parameters to add the text from my text boxes into a SQL database.

I've tested the connection and it is opening ok but I still get the exception from the try, catch statement. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyAdventureWorks;Trusted_Connection=yes;");


            SqlCommand addEmployee = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.DimEmployee (ParentEmployeeKey, FirstName, LastName, NameStyle, CurrentFlag, SalesPersonFlag)" + "Values (@parentEmployeeKey,@firstName, @lastName, @nameStyle, @currentFlag, @salesPersonFlag)", cnn);

            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentEmployeeKey", textBox1.Text);
            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", textBox2.Text);
            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", textBox3.Text);
            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameStyle", textBox4.Text);
            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentFlag", textBox5.Text);
            addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesFlag", textBox6.Text);

            cnn.Open();
            addEmployee.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Employee added to database");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An unknown error occured");
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception _exactly_?

Comment: The line [MessageBox.Show("An unknown error occured");] can be modified to show the actual error as stored in the ex variable. Then you will know exactly what went wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the case, you define your last parameter in your command as `@salesPersonFlag` but you try to add this value in your parameter collection with `@salesFlag` name. They should be the same.

Change your

```
addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesFlag", textBox6.Text);
```

to

```
addEmployee.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesPersonFlag", textBox6.Text);
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close()` methods manually.

And don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var addEmployee = con.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property
    // Add your parameter values with Add method3
    // Open your connection
    // Execute your query
}
```

Comment: Hi. My bad I mistyped my variab;e, however it sill does not work.

Comment: Could you show me how to use the connection through 'using' also?

Comment: @NickProud I _did_ in my example. Can you please be more specific about _does not work_ exactly? What exception or error message you get? Without these information, it is not possible to help you.